# Multiple routed multicast groups on single switch

Tags: routing, multicast, pim

This is my lab environment:
I have two rooms with one L2 access switch each with multiple vlans. The switches are connected to a L3 switch. All routing happens on this switch.

I was able to configure pim in dm mode just fine. But then all multicasts are flooded to both rooms. The desired configuration is the following:

I would like to separate the two rooms in two different routed multicast groups. Per example VLAN 1 to 10 as multicast group 1 and VLAN 11 to 20 as multicast group 2. If in any way possible I don't want to change the client software's configuration. Means, I use the same multicast ip address in both multicast groups. But since they are not routed, I only reach the clients in the room I set the multicast off.

Is this somehow technically possible? I'm using Huawei switches by the way. They support different PIM modes for multicast routing.

Thank you very much for your input.

Kind regards,
Thomas

Comment: The simplest way would be to switch to sparse mode.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated by Ron Trunk you will need to use PIM Sparse mode. The Huawei switches support this feature and i've linked the configuration guide in the following link. See chapter 7 for a complete walk through.

[enterprise.huawei.com/ilink/enenterprise/download/hw_116586](http://enterprise.huawei.com/ilink/enenterprise/download/hw_116586)